# Android Spinner Width

Tags: android, width, android-spinner

I have a spinner which has several options with the last option being Choose Date...

The spinner currently selects it's size based on the longest option but what I want for it to do is to choose it's width based on the width of the option which is currently selected.  So if option with text "one" is selected then the spinner should be much shorter then when option "one one one" is selected.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks,
Nathan